# ERROR in c program: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c, math.h

This is a simple program to draw the sine curve using c program. unfortunately,I got this error :
 `undefined reference to 'sin'`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
main()
{
    int i;
    int offset;
    char sinstr[80];
    memset(sinstr,0x20,80);
    sinstr[79] = '\0';
    for(i= 0; i<20; i++)
    {
        offset =39 +(int)(39 * sin(M_PI * (float) i/10));
        sinstr[offset] = '*';
        printf("%s\n", sinstr);
        sinstr[offset] = ' ';
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be very useful if you actually told use the exact error message you get. As it is, we'd need to guess.

Comment: which error??..specify it first.

Comment: On which operating system? If on Linux, compile with `gcc -Wall -g sample.c -lm -o sample-prog`

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: note that you can use printf to do a number of spaces, without needing sinstr: `printf("%*s*", offset, "");`

Comment: Please stop with the random rollbacks to keep "bumping" your question. If this persists, I will lock this from further editing.

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget to add the compiler option `-lm` in order to link to the math library.

E.g.: `gcc -o myapp main.c -lm`

Comment: Passing `-Wall -g` to `gcc` is also useful.

Comment: `-Wall -Wextra` is my motto.